# Issue parsing multiline JSON file using Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, multiline

I am trying to parse a JSON multiline file using `json` library in Python 2.7. A simplified sample file is given below:

```
{
"observations": {
    "notice": [
        {
            "copyright": "Copyright Commonwealth of Australia 2015, Bureau of Meteorology. For more information see: http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml",
            "copyright_url": "http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml",
            "disclaimer_url": "http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml",
            "feedback_url": "http://www.bom.gov.au/other/feedback"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    for jf in jsonFile:
        jf = jf.replace('\n', '')
        jf = jf.strip()
        weatherData = json.loads(jf)
        print weatherData
```

Nevertheless, I get an error as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
weatherData = json.loads(jf)
File "/home/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/home/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/home/usr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting object: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Just to do some testing, I modified the code such that after removing newlines and striping away the leading and trailing white spaces, I write the contents to another file (with the `json` extension). Surprisingly, when I read back the latter file, I do not get any error and the parsing is successful. The modified code is as follows:

```
import json

filewrite = open('out.json', 'w+')

with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    for jf in jsonFile:
        jf = jf.replace('\n', '')
        jf = jf.strip()
        filewrite.write(jf)

filewrite.close()

with open('out.json', 'r') as newJsonFile:
    for line in newJsonFile:
        weatherData = json.loads(line)
        print weatherData
```

The output is as follows:

```
{u'observations': {u'notice': [{u'copyright_url': u'http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml', u'disclaimer_url': u'http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml', u'copyright': u'Copyright Commonwealth of Australia 2015, Bureau of Meteorology. For more information see: http://www.bom.gov.au/other/copyright.shtml http://www.bom.gov.au/other/disclaimer.shtml', u'feedback_url': u'http://www.bom.gov.au/other/feedback'}]}}
```

Any idea what might be going on when new lines and white spaces are stripped before using `json` library?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will go *crazy* if you try to parse a json file line by line. The json module has helper methods to read file objects directly or strings i.e. the `load` and `loads` methods.  `load` takes a file object (as shown below) for a file that contains json data, while `loads` takes a string that contains json data.

Option 1: - **Preferred**

```
import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as jf:
    weatherData = json.load(jf)
    print weatherData
```

Option 2:

```
import json
with open('test.json', 'r') as jf:
    weatherData = json.loads(jf.read())
    print weatherData
```

If you are looking for higher performance json parsing check out [ujson](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson)

Comment: Thank you @OkezieE. Loading the entire file via `load` does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

In the first snippet, you try to parse it line by line. You should parse it all at once. The easiest is to use `json.load(jsonfile)`. (The jf variable name is misleading as it's a string). So the correct way to parse it:

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as jsonFile:
    weatherData = json.loads(jsonFile)
```

Although it's a good idea to store the json in one line, as it's more concise.

In the second snippet your problem is that you print it as unicode string which is and `u'string here'` is python specific. A valid json uses double quotation marks

Comment: I tried your approach of loading the entire file and parsing all at once, but It fails. By the way, I have tried parsing json files earlier line by line without having any issues, expect that each dictionary never exceeded about a 100 characters long.

Comment: For my it was working fine with the json you provided. Try using the Sublime JSON plugin for converting the json back and forth: https://github.com/dzhibas/SublimePrettyJson It also validates the json, so you can investigate the issue further. For more detailed linting try http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 2):

FYI, you can have both files opened in single `with` statement:

```
with open('file_A') as in_, open('file_B', 'w+') as out_:
    # logic here
    ...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10682568)

Comment: @James: agreed. at the moment of answering I was not able to comment on questions and thanks to upvote now I can :-)